# How to draw table Using CGContextRendering in ios?

Tags: ios, ipad, cgcontext

I want to draw table Like display in Image. User requirement is draw table dynamically using the Get web services data. All column and row are getting using the Web services.

**Cell width are also depend on length of string**, and cell also clickable. Means user press any particular cell then find the particular cell and call the web services. **Cell also Editable**. Cell into also different background color.

[image]

Below is a screen shot of Table. How can I do that?

Please provide information related to draw table. **Is it Possible to Draw Table Using CGContextRendering ?**

Comment: You can not draw table using CGContextRendering unless drawing all the lines and texts... I suggest you to use basic iOS UI components, doing the layout programatically. Since you mentioned using an image you can very easily create an image from UIView (screenshot).

Comment: Not preferred from what point of view? Doing this from what you posted seems quite easy to make.

Comment: I have overridden an UIScrollView